# Converting DXF to KML with ogr2ogr

Tags: convert, kml, ogr2ogr, dxf, spain

I want to convert DXF from AutoCAD to KML. It works but the coordinates don't come out right when I compare them to a KML produced with global_mapper and consequently it is shifted some when uploading the KML to Google Earth. Maybe someone can illustrate me how to set/calculate the parameters right to adjust the shift?

```
ogr2ogr -f KML -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=-36.7193107889714,-4.418216852011938,0,0,0 +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs " -t_srs epsg:25830 -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from entities where layer='SUPERFICIES  ZV'" SUPERFICIES_ZV.kml D02-32.dxf
```

Southern Spain ETRS89 30 [EPSG:25830](https://epsg.io/25830)

Comment: Parameter `-t_srs epsg:25830` does not make sense because KML is always in EPSG:4326 but perhaps GDAL just skips that part. Where have you found the +towgs84 parameters? Have you tried not to use them?

Comment: of course. Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I have edited the command

```
ogr2ogr -f KML -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs " -t_srs epsg:4326 -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from entities where layer='SUPERFICIES  ZV'" SUPERFICIES_ZV.kml D02-32.dxf
```